# How to run asp.net webpage on the localhost

Tags: asp.net

I am just learning asp.net and have created a simple webform on visual studio. How I can run this on the localhost(xampp). Like HTML you simply put files to the server folder and it works. But when I copy all asp files it simply shows me source code?

It is stupid question but I really need answer...

Answer (score 1):

ASP (ActiveX Server Pages) is a deprecated technology (superseded by ASP.NET). Thus support is not included as standard in IIS. But it can be added by using Server Manager under Roles | Web Server (IIS) and scrolling down to Role Services.

If you however mean ASP.NET then, initially, look at the Web tab of the project properties and start in VS for debug and test. Once that is working you'll need to read up on deploying ASP.NET on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To host a ASP.Net page you usually use IIS. You are supposed to run IIS on your server and host the ASP.NET website on the IIS Management

[This Article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33487zw6.aspx) should help you with that.

Also, you usually use visual studio to 'Publish' to the server folder, rather then copy and paste the files. In case you didn't do this: this is done by right-clicking the project in visual studio and selecting 'Publish'. Then there are a few options, you can publish to a folder (File System) and then move the published project to your server, or publish it straight to your server.

Comment: In this article first is like to run 'inetmgr' however it throws me error like it cannot be founded....

Comment: @EimantasBaigys This should be done on the server, you might want to check if you have IIS installed on your server if it throws that error.

Comment: @EimantasBaigys - IIS is not installed by default. See control panel, under "programs" there is a "Windows features" link. Search for "Internet Information Services"